# How to retrieve a collection which is inside another collection in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have a collection of the following structure:
[ {Object1} {Object2} ]

Now Object1 = { CollectionA : [{}, {}]} and Object2 = { CollectionB: [{}, {}]

How do I access CollectionA or CollectionB?

Comment: Ideally collection should be a collection of models. You can then have a property in each model pointing to a collection

Comment: Yup, should be collection get by ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access them in following way:

```
collection
    .at(0) //get first element in collection
    .get('CollectionA') //get CollectionA property
```

You can also find a model with `CollectionA` property by using `collection.get` and passing model's `id`.